# DolphinDB: Multiple curves on the same plot

Tags: plot, graph, dolphindb

How to plot Multiple lines in one plot in DolphinDB?

Also I would like to know if there is a command which allows saving the plot automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `plot(data, [labels], [title], [chartType=LINE])`:

For example:

```
x = 0.1*(1..100)
y = 0.1*(100..1)
t =table(x, y)
plot([sin,cos](x),x,"cos and sin curve")
```